# How to maintain the oauth session object between requests with django?

Tags: python, django, oauth

I am using the [Requests-Oauthlib1 workflow](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html) to authenticate on a site with oauth 1 from django.

I think I am not using the one obvious way to do it.
The way I have implemented it:

**/oauth** - Gets the request token and returns the oauth authorization url

```
def oauth(request):

    oauth_service = Oauth_service()
    key, secret = oauth_service.obtain_request_token()

    message = oauth_service.get_authorization_url()

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**/oauthcomplete** - oauth success redirects here, but I am now creating a new instance of the `Oath_Service` which won't have the request token and secret

```
def oauth_complete(request):

    oauth_service = Oauth_service()
    verifier = oauth_service.get_verifier(request.build_absolute_uri())

    return HttpResponse("Verified with {}".format(verifier))
```

**oauth_service.py**

```
class Oauth_service:
    '''
    Class used to commuicate with an Oauth magento
    '''

    BASE_URL = 'https://xxx'

    RETRIEVE_REQUEST_TOKEN_PATH = '/oauth/initiate'
    ADMIN_AUTHORIZATION_PATH = '/admin/oauth_authorize'
    RETRIEVE_ACCESS_TOKEN_PATH = '/oauth/token'

    OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
    OAUTH_SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'
    OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD = 'HMAC-SHA1'

    CALLBACK_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/models/oauth_complete'

    oauth = OAuth1Session(  
            OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, 
            client_secret=OAUTH_SECRET_KEY,
            callback_uri=CALLBACK_URL,
        )

    resource_owner_key = ''
    resource_owner_secret = ''
    verifier = ''

    def obtain_request_token(self):
        '''
        step 1 in oauth process
        '''

        request_token_url = self.BASE_URL + self.RETRIEVE_REQUEST_TOKEN_PATH

        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

        fetch_response = self.oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url, verify=False, headers=headers)

        self.resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get('oauth_token')
        self.resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')

        return self.resource_owner_key, self.resource_owner_secret

    def get_authorization_url(self):

        base_authorization_url = self.BASE_URL + self.ADMIN_AUTHORIZATION_PATH

        authorization_url = self.oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)

        return 'Please go here and authorize, {}'.format(authorization_url)

    def get_verifier(self, url):
        oauth_response = self.oauth.parse_authorization_response(url)
        verifier = oauth_response.get('oauth_verifier')

        return verifier
```

It feels like I am doing this in a strange way with use of class variables that are updated but do not persist. As those class variables won't be their when a new instance of the service is created.

I am trying to maintain the `OauthSession1` instance during the full oauth workflow.

Comment: did you try `request.session` ?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: No, I haven't. Do you mean for storing the request tokens and secrets. Or for the whole `OauthSession1` object?

Comment: whatever you need for the flow just store it in the session and then remove it when the flow is completed.